# What line of code is written first in Software development?

Tags: design, programming-practices, scrum, software, devops

When building software, we usually go through the requirements phase to design and all the stuff but when we start writing the actual code, how do we decide on which parts of the software will be build first . What is the first line of code to be written? I think we should start by writing tests for the functionalities and then continue working on making each test pass rather that diving straight into coding the actual application. E.g. We write tests for a login controller first before implementing the controller. I don't expect anyone to agree with me. I'm just trying to learn. Your thoughts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: It depends. Please see the [How do I ask a good question?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page to understand how to ask a good question :)

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315684/what-line-of-code-is-written-first-in-software-development "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: What you describe (first write the tests) is the philosophy of [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (TDD). But there are many ways to develop software and TDD is of course not the only possible choice.

Comment: Note that in TDD, normally you'd write a single failing test, then the code to make it pass, then another failing test, then make that one pass, and so on. It's a more unusual approach to write all the tests for a unit, then make all of them pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are designing the application from scratch, you would need to write your Login, Design your framework, decide on your technologies to use. However, I have only done that only a few times in my career.

Normally, I do get to start with a new functionality that needs to be added/modified. If all my requirements are done, I am usually trying to find my POCO/Domain objects. I am then writing my Interfaces to get a blueprint for getting my estimates and then I get to write my test cases. After I have done my test cases, I do get into the crux of code.

Hope that may have provided you some insight.

Comment: Thanks for your input Amit. What are your thoughts on my approach to writing tests first. Does it make sense to start with that?

Comment: You  are definitely on the right track when you think about writing test code. No one can question that approach.